# How to know if a function evaluates its arguments?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, evaluation, clisp

How to know if a function evaluates its arguments?

Setq seems not to evaluate its arguments but

```
Break 15 [16]> (setq j (kjl klj))
*** - EVAL: undefined function KJL
```

So when is the evaluation done?

`cond` and `and` seem not to evaluate their arguments as well but...

```
Break 18 [19]> (cond ((eql nil nil) (write "lkj")))
"lkj"
"lkj"
Break 18 [19]> (cond ((eql nil (not nil)) (write "lkj"))
NIL
```

in the example above `cond` has to evaluate `(eql nil nil)` to know if it's true or not, hasn't it?

Comment: Functions *always* evaluate their arguments. `setq` and `cond` are not functions, however; `setq` is a special form and `cond` is a macro.

Comment: All functions evaluate all their arguments. To know a language you need to know their special forms and the core procedures. In addition, knowing and using naming conventions give lispers clues even before reading documentation.

Comment: There is no concept of a "primitive" in CL. That's a part of its beauty: you can build the language ground up the way you like it and decide what is a primitive yourself.

Comment: @sds There's no "primitive", but as you explain in your answer, there are *special operators*.  You'll need at least some special operators to implement a useful language;  you can't really build ground up without them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Theory: [Form Evaluation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aba.htm)

### Functions

The runtime evaluates the arguments before passing them to a [function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababc.htm) (such as [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm)).

E.g., when you write `(eql a 1)`, the function `eql` gets the value of the variable `a` and the value of the literal `1` which is itself.

### Macros

The runtime does *not* evaluate the arguments of [macros](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababb.htm) (such as [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) and [`and`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_and.htm)).
Macros convert their arguments to code which is then evaluated by the runtime.

E.g., when you write `cond ((eql nil nil) (write "lkj")))`, it is expanded to something like:

```
> (macroexpand '(cond ((eql nil nil) (write "lkj"))))
(IF (EQL NIL NIL)
    (PROGN (WRITE "lkj"))
    NIL)
```

and then the [`if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm) form is evaluated according to its spec as the special operator.

Of course, you don't want to actually read the macroexpansion of [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) to understand what it does - you read the doc. However, you do use [`macroexpand`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm) to debug your own macros.

### Special Operators

The runtime handles [special operators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm) (such as [`setq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm)), well, *specially*, i.e., the behavior is idiosyncratic to each special operator.

E.g., when you write `(setq a (! 4))`, the runtime does *not* evaluate `a`, it does, however, evaluate `(! 4)`, it discovers that `!` is fbound to a function, so it evaluates `4` (it [evaluates to itself](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abac.htm)), then calls the function binding of `!` with argument `4`, and assigns the return value (`24`) to the variable `a`.

### Order

Actually, as @Paulo mentioned in the comments, the symbol is checked for being a special operator first (because an implementation can implement a macro as a special operator and vv); it cannot be a macro and a function at the same time (but you can use [compiler macros](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_define.htm)). This is out of the scope of this question though...

## Practice: Use CLHS

Edit your code in Emacs, load [clhs.el](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/emacs/clhs.el), and view the doc of the symbol you are interested in.
The do will say right away what the symbol is defined as.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Do you know other common primitives than quote that don't evaluate their arguments?

Comment: You are welcome! I am not sure what you mean by "primitive". If you click on links in my answers, you will find that section 3.1.2.1.2.1 lists the Common Lisp special operators in Figure 3-2. `psetq` and `setq` evaluate their even args but not odd args....

Comment: IOW, asking about "other common primitives than quote that don't evaluate their arguments" is not a very meaningful thing. Think of what you want to do and how CL can help you, not what features CL provides. CL standard has ~1k symbols (and that's just the standard - any implementation brings at least as much in extensions).

Comment: I'm writing a lisp interpreter for curses and the prof ask to implement 3 primitives that don't evaluate their arguments, that why I'm asking this.

Comment: ah... okay, try `quote`, `setq`, `if` - these are sufficiently diverse and important; I think your prof will like this choice :-)

Comment: The lookup is actually done in reverse: special operator, macro, function.

Comment: @PauloMadeira - yes, I listed them in the order of complexity for didactic purposes; I will add a note, thanks.